# squid:S2259 and Apache Commons

Tags: sonarqube

Consider the following code:

```
private boolean hasEnabledBluetooth() {
    final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = getBluetoothAdapter();
    Validate.notNull(bluetoothAdapter);
    return bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
}
```

The last line, `return bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();` , triggers **squid:S2259** (in SonarQube 5.6.4 LTS)

> NullPointerException might be thrown as 'bluetoothAdapter' is nullable here

This is not true. `bluetoothAdapter` is not nullable here, as Apache commons `Validate.notNull()` will throw an exception if that would be the case.

**Is this a known issue? Will it be fixed?**

Update:

Per request, the complete source code (within the same file):

```
private BluetoothAdapter getBluetoothAdapter() {
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getBluetoothManager();
    Validate.notNull(bluetoothManager);
    return bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
}

BluetoothManager getBluetoothManager() {
    return (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: What is the version of the java analyzer you are using ?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce the issue anymore. Not sure what has changed. Version: 4.3.0.7717.

Comment: Can someone confirm that this has been fixed recently (in the java analyzer)?

Comment: From what I can see in the release notes that should not be fixed and I would expect to have the issue raised. I'll try to investigate to the why of this.

Comment: Any news on this? I don't see it anymore so it might have been a sync problem with the SonarLint plugin in IntelliJ.

Comment: Is the getBluetoothAdapter method annotated with @CheckForNull ? Is the code of that method within the same file ? if yes, could you share it ? 4.3 of SonarJava analyzer is doing cross procedural analysis so this code may have an impact on this issue.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post with these details. No @CheckForNull

Comment: Same question for getSystemService then : is it annotated ? is it within the same source file ?

Comment: getSystemService() is a method defined in the Android native base class which this class extends (android.app.Activity). So it is not annotated.

Comment: Ok I cannot reproduce and there is no reason why this issue would be triggered (and why would you need a Validate.notNull) ?

Comment: Same here... I guess we can conclude that this is not a problem in SQ 5.6.4 (but possibly in 5.4).
We want to fail fast, reduces complexity to do these validations early. Also the cause of the NPE is very clear if seeing this in the logs when the validation fails in the beginning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132921/discussion-between-alix-and-benzonico).

Comment: Any updates on this? We're seeing the exact same effect since upgrading to SonarQube 5.6.5